# how to design Linear layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-cardview, androiddesignsupport

how can I do something like this programmatically? There must be one Checkbox and two vertical textview in MaterialCardView.I tried using Linearlayout but I can't solve it.
[image]

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

    );
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mCardView=new MaterialCardView(this);
    mCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    mCardView.setElevation(2);
    linearLayout.addView(mCardView);

    LinearLayout linearLayout1=new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayout1)

    checkBox=new CheckBox(this);
    linearLayout1.addView(checkBox);
    txt_baslik=new TextView(this);
    txt_tarih=new TextView(this);
    txt_baslik.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    txt_tarih.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    txt_baslik.setText("deneme baslik");
    txt_tarih.setText("deneme tarih");
    linearLayout1.addView(txt_baslik);
    linearLayout1.addView(txt_baslik);

    LinearLayout linearLayout2=new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayout2);
```

I'm so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like that :

[image]

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

CardView mCardView=new MaterialCardView(this);
mCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
mCardView.setElevation(2);

CheckBox checkBox=new CheckBox(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkBoxParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
checkBoxParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
checkBox.setLayoutParams(checkBoxParam);

LinearLayout verticalLinLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
verticalLinLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
verticalLinLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

TextView txt_baslik=new TextView(this);
TextView txt_tarih=new TextView(this);

txt_baslik.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
txt_tarih.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

txt_baslik.setText("deneme baslik");
txt_tarih.setText("deneme tarih");

verticalLinLayout.removeAllViews();
verticalLinLayout.addView(txt_baslik);
verticalLinLayout.addView(txt_tarih);
linearLayout.addView(checkBox);
linearLayout.addView(verticalLinLayout);
mCardView.addView(linearLayout);
```

**don't forgor add mCardView into your parent view at last.**

Comment: thank you so much for your answer . code worked but I can't add vertically consecutively

Comment: If you want to repeat view its batter to use RecycleView instead of this way.